# Flutter, floating action button margin of Scaffold

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a custom implementation for flutter of the `FloatingActionButton`, something to replace the standard widget on the `Scaffold.floatingActionButton` attribute.

The problem is that there is a 16 bottom right margin whatever I try to render within that field, and the only workaround I found is to set that margin to zero in the Scaffold class in the flutter library.

Did anyone found a better solution?

Comment: Since Scaffold is for material design it's most likely intented. 
You'd have to contribute by  adding a new property to `Scaffold` which default to the current value.

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample code for checking.

> It set 100 margin and you can change as per your requirement.

[image]

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Add your onPressed code here!
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
          backgroundColor:Colors.blue,
          tooltip: "Raise Your Concern"),
bottomSheet: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0)),
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a Padding to the bottomSheet property in Scaffold

```
bottomSheet: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0)),
```

Answer (score 1):

You will provide in builder Material App Global Padding it looks like the code in below.

check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14222#issuecomment-384165992

Also, provide code

```
   double getSmartBannerHeight(MediaQueryData mediaQuery) {
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#smart_banners
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    if (mediaQuery.size.height > 720) return 90.0;
    if (mediaQuery.size.height > 400) return 50.0;
    return 32.0;
  }
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner#smart_banners
  // Smart Banners on iPhones have a height of 50 points in portrait and 32 points in landscape.
  // On iPads, height is 90 points in both portrait and landscape.
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    // TODO use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info to detect iPhone/iPad?
    // if (iPad) return 90.0;
    if (mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.portrait) return 50.0;
    return 32.0;
  }
  // No idea, just return a common value.
  return 50.0;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    // ...
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
      final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
      return new Padding(
        child: widget,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: getSmartBannerHeight(mediaQuery)),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set floatingActionButtonLocation inside your Scaffold to

```
FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked
```

This will replace margin from each side with 0 and align the FloatingActionButton at the screen center. Then just wrap your Floating widget with Align widget and set the alignment property to

```
Alignment.bottomRight
```

so that it renders at the right-bottom part of the screen. The margin will be zero. If you need to add margin, then you'll have to wrap your Floating widget with a Padding widget.

Note that only the FloatingActionButton should be wrapped with Align widget so that it does not create any problems with displaying a snackbar as they are connected in some way. (For example if you use ValueListenableBuilder above your custom FloatingActionButton or AnimatedOpacity/AnimatedSwitcher, etc. then you'll have to place Align widget beneath them, as a direct parent of the button)